# Declare function params outside function to reuse in python

Tags: python

I have a function that works like a real champ:

```
def example(
  foo: str = None,
  bar: str = None
):
  return(foo, bar)
```

I want to wrap this function in another function and pass through the args. Is there a way to declare the function args outside the function, to reuse them in another function?

**How I wish it would work:**

```
# this does not work:
ExampleArgs = (foo: str = None, bar: str = None)

def example(ExampleArgs):
  return(foo, bar)

def otherFunction(
  exampleArgs: ExampleArgs,
  other: str = "Yay"
):
  list = example(exampleArgs)
  # now I got list and can reuse its items / content
  

# How I would like to use it
result = otherFunction(
  exampleArgs =(
    foo = "Hey",
    bar = "You"
  )
)
```

I have searched for it, but I only did find a lot of information about global used variables.

Comment: No. But you may be looking for `*args, **kwargs`…?!

Comment: What is ``result`` going to be? When would ``example`` actually run? Are you looking for [``partial`` functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) perhaps?

Comment: Function 1 is something like a filter, that supports multiple parameters. In Function 2 I want to reuse the filter function and keep the parameters up to date, without duplicating each param. That's a common thing to do in javascript, but it seems unpopular in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Pythonic way to achieve what you want (type annotations included) is by defining the desired parameters as a `typing.NamedTuple`:

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class ExampleArgs(NamedTuple):
    foo: str = None
    bar: str = None

def example(args: ExampleArgs):
    return args.foo, args.bar

def otherFunction(
    exampleArgs: ExampleArgs,
    other: str = "Yay"
):
    return example(exampleArgs)

result = otherFunction(
    exampleArgs=ExampleArgs(
        foo="Hey",
        bar="You"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your arguments as a dictionary and then use kwargs of the function. For example:

```
ExampleArgs = {"foo": None, "bar": None}
```

Then following your idea:

```
def example(
     foo: str = None,
     bar: str = None):
  print(foo, bar)

def otherFunction(
  other: str = "Yay",
  **exampleArgs
):
  ex = example(**exampleArgs)


result = otherFunction(
  **{"foo": "Hey",
     "bar": "You"}
  )
```

Example:

```
>>> ExampleArgs = {"foo": None, "bar": "Hello"}
>>> example(**ExampleArgs)
None Hello
>>> example(**{"foo": "Hello", "bar": "world!"})
Hello world!
>>> otherFunction(**ExampleArgs)
None Hello
>>> otherFunction(**{"foo": "Hello", "bar": "world!"})
Hello world!
```

You can even pass only one argument:

```
>>> otherFunction(**{"foo": "Hello"})
Hello None
>>> otherFunction(**{"bar": "world!"})
None world!
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing the solution. It’s a great idea, but works only with one nested function if I understand it correctly? Images another function B and C, which although should receive their arguments. Than the **args operator is unspecific and every function would receive every argument. Or do I miss out on something?

Comment: @Marian Every argument *not otherwise explicitly declared*. In your example, `other` would be picked out, and only the remaining arguments would be passed through.

Answer (score 0):

The way this usually goes in Python is that you pass arguments through using the `*args, **kwargs` mechanism:

```
def inner(foo, bar):
    return foo, bar

def outer(other, *args, **kwargs):
    res = inner(*args, **kwargs)
    print(other, 'result from inner:', res)

outer(42, 'foo', 'bar')  # or even outer(42, foo='foo', bar='bar')
```

`outer` here is sort of a wrapper around `inner`, accepting all its arguments *plus* additional arguments. This is hiding `inner` as an implementation detail of `outer`, but still requires the caller to sort of know about what kinds of arguments `inner` accepts (or you need to mirror all of `inner`'s parameters at least in `outer`'s documentation, otherwise users may be somewhat lost as to what arguments they're supposed to pass).

An alternative approach would be to leave `inner` up to the caller and accept it as a callback:

```
from functools import partial

def inner(foo, bar):
    return foo, bar

def outer(other, inner):
    res = inner()
    print(other, 'result from inner:', res)

outer(42, partial(inner, 'foo', 'bar'))  # alternatively: outer(42, lambda: inner('foo', 'bar'))
```

The correct design depends on your priorities and goals.